# PostgreSQL server process was terminated by signal 11

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL v11.0. I am executing a simple SQL query

`delete from base.sys_attribute where id=20;`

It fails and returns the error:

`server process (PID 29) was terminated by signal 11` (see log below)

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue? I'm completely stuck...

```
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:54:46.425 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:54:46.425 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:54:46.425 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:54:46.435 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-10 08:54:26 UTC
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:54:46.438 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 29) was terminated by signal 11
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: delete from base.sys_attribute where id=20
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [24] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [24] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.295 UTC [24] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:52.486 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.093 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-05-10 08:54:46 UTC
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.187 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.189 UTC [30] LOG:  redo starts at 0/75955A8
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.189 UTC [30] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/75971B8: wanted 24, got 0
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.189 UTC [30] LOG:  redo done at 0/7597180
listof-db  | 2019-05-10 08:56:53.194 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: That means either a software bug or fauly memory or data corruption. Does upgrading to 11.3 help? Are you using third-party extensions?

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe I'm using pgcrypto but not in this table... Any advice about how I could do an upgrade? it's usually not trivial for a database.

Comment: Minor upgrades *are* trivial, install the software and restart. Read the release notes for additional information. It's basically risk-free.